# Scan through nested json response for a specific value without knowing names

Tags: python, json

I have a massive (over 3000 lines) JSON response I am receiving from a UI. I need to scan through the entire response and search for the value "Not Answered". Once I find this value, I then need to get the other info around that response.

The response is heavily nested, up to 7 layers. I do know that the value has a key of "value", but that key is in the response multiple times. The number of nests and items under the first "value" key can be different for each call.

This is an example of a small piece of what the response can look like. I would need to find each instance of the value "Not Answered". I am not showing the other data within the response under the value keys.

```
{
"data": {
 "reviewData": [
   0: {
     "value": [
       1: {
         "value": "Answer"
       },
       2: {
         "value": "Not Answered"
       },
       3: {
         "value": "Answer"
       }
     ]
   },
   1: {
     "value": [
       1: {
         "value": "Not Answered"
       },
       2: {
         "value": "Not Answered"
       },
       3: {
         "value": "Answer"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
 }
}
```

I understand that I could just put this all into a string and use regex but that wouldn't assist in getting the other data that I need. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Could you give your example in a json format ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a generator to walk through your dictionary and yield the paths that lead to `'Not Answered'` values in form of tuples:

```
def walk(obj):
    for key, value in obj.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            yield from ((key,) + x for x in walk(value))
        elif value == 'Not Answered':
            yield (key,)
```

For your example this gives the following output:

```
[('data', 'reviewData', '0', 'value', '2', 'value'),
 ('data', 'reviewData', '1', 'value', '1', 'value'),
 ('data', 'reviewData', '1', 'value', '2', 'value')]
```

If you need access to the surrounding information you can `reduce` the provided paths to any depth by using `__getitem__` on the nested dicts:

```
from functools import reduce

for path in walk(test_dict):
    info = reduce(lambda obj, key: obj[key], path[:-1], test_dict)
```

Comment: This works very well. Except I am having an issue getting the values within arrays. I have updated my example to show what I mean

Comment: I got it working. I made a second function just like yours to handle arrays and I toss the data back and forth. Thanks!

Comment: @tdlanghe Sure you can add an extra `isinstance` check for that (or create a separate generator). But as it stands now, the example dict in your question is not valid syntax. Something with the lists got messed up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive function like this one:

```
def find_not_anwsered_object(obj, sink):
    for key in obj.keys():
        if obj[key] == "Not Answered":
            sink.append(obj)
        elif isinstance(obj[key], dict):
            find_not_answered_object(obj[key], sink)


    return sink

response = {} # your JSON response
print(find_not_answered_object(response, [])
```